# Play Again function in kivy

Tags: python, oop, kivy, kivy-language

I am  currently building a game with kivy. Everything works fine except the play again button.
So here is what I want for my play again. The score should be set to 0 and everything has to freeze and a play again button should appear. When I click on it the enemies should respawn to the top. 
I tried to t´do it with Clock.schedule_interval and Clock.unschedule_interval. But that only works for the resume button. When I try it with enemies. Everything freezes but then when I click play again. Nothing happens. And the score also doesn't go to 0.
Here is my code:

Main GameClass: The play again button appers after stop game. And then when I click on it it does not unfreeze

```
  class PongGame(Widget):
    ball = ObjectProperty(None)
    ship = ObjectProperty(None)
    enemy = ObjectProperty(None)
    badenemy = ObjectProperty(None)
    resume_button = ObjectProperty(None)
    play_again = ObjectProperty(None)
    x_change = NumericProperty(3)
    start_button = ObjectProperty(None)

    label_text = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(PongGame, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.count = 0
        self.label_text = str(self.count)

    def increment(self, **kwargs):
        self.count += 5
        self.label_text = str(self.count)
        print(self.label_text)  
    enemies = ListProperty([])
    badenemies = ListProperty([])
    def add_enemy(self, *args):
        enemy = Enemy()
        enemy.pos = (random.randint(0,600),random.randint(30,600))
        self.add_widget(enemy)
        self.enemies.append(enemy)

    def add_badenemy(self, *args):
        badenemy = BadEnemy()
        badenemy.pos = (random.randint(0,600),randint(350,600))
        self.add_widget(badenemy)
        self.badenemies.append(badenemy)

    def update(self,dt):
        self.ball.move()

        for enemy in self.enemies:
            enemy.move()
            enemy.collision(self.ball)
            enemy.ship_collision(self.ship)

        for badenemy in self.badenemies:
            badenemy.move()
    def stop(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.update)
        Clock.unschedule(self.add_enemy)
        self.resume_button.x = self.width / 2.25 -50
        self.resume_button.y = self.height - 350

    def resume(self):
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.update, 1 / 60.0)
        self.count = 0
        new_enemy_event = Clock.schedule_interval(self.add_enemy, 2)
        self.resume_button.x = 1000
        self.resume_button.y = 1000

    def stop_game(self):
        Clock.unschedule(self.update)
        Clock.unschedule(self.add_enemy)
        Clock.unschedule(self.add_badenemy)
        self.count = 0
        self.play_again.x = self.width / 2.25 - 50
        self.play_again.y = self.height - 350
```

Enemy Class. So here I cant call the stopgame function

```
class Enemy(Widget):
    x_change = NumericProperty(3)
    y_change = NumericProperty(-50)
    score = NumericProperty(0)

    def collision(self, ball):
        if self.collide_widget(ball):
            self.y = 1000
            PongGame.increment(self.parent)
            ball.x = -1000
            ball.y = self.height / self.width

    def ship_collision(self,ship):
        if self.collide_widget(ship):
            PongGame.stop_game(self.parent)

    def move(self, *args):
        self.x -= self.x_change
        if self.x >= self.parent.width - 64:
            self.x_change = 3
            self.y += self.y_change
        elif self.x <= 0:
            self.x_change = -3
            self.y += self.y_change
```

App class

```
class PongApp(App):
    def build(self):
        game = PongGame()
        # game.serve_ball()
        # pro second 60 frames are shown
        self.sound = SoundLoader.load('kgf.mp3')
        self.sound.play()

        Clock.schedule_interval(self.loop_sound, 1)
        return game
```

Some of my kv code

```
<PongGame>:
    ball: pong_ball
    ship: space_ship
    start_button: start_button
    resume_button:resume_button
    play_again:play_again

    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'background.png'
    Label:
        font_size: 40
        x:root.width/ 1/4 +70
        y:root.height -350
        text: 'Your score :'

    Label:
        font_size: 40
        x:root.width/ 1/2
        y:root.height -350
        text: root.label_text

Button:
        id:play_again
        font_size:40
        size:200,100
        x:10000
        y:10000
        text:'Play Again'
        on_release:
            self.parent.play_again_game()
PongBall:
        id: pong_ball
        x: root.width /1.4
        y: root.height / root.width
    SpaceShip:
        id: space_ship
        x: root.width / 2.25
        y: root.height / root.width +60
```

So I think my main problem is ,that I cant refer to the method in my game class. And my score is not going to 0. I think I just cant write self.count = 0